# How to do GROUP BY on exploded field in Spark SQL's?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-1.6

- Zeppelin 0.6
- Spark 1.6
- SQL

I am trying to find the top 20 occurring words in some tweets. `filtered` contains an array of words for each tweet. The following:

```
select explode(filtered) AS words from tweettable
```

lists each word as you would expect, but what I want is to get a count of each word over all tweets and then display the top 20 of these. The following works but I need to do this in SQL:

```
df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value"))
  .groupBy("value")
  .count()
  .sort(desc("count"))
  .show(20, false)
```

I tried `GROUP BY` on `words`, `filtered`, and `explode(filtered)` but all gave errors.

Comment: Why have you changed the title? It does not make sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `subqueries` in the `FROM` statement:

```
SELECT value, count(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT explode(filtered) AS value
      FROM tweettable) AS temp
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will give you complete idea to achieve what you are expecting. Tested in Spark(1.6)

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._

val lst = List(Seq("Hello","Hyd","Hello","Mumbai"),Seq("Hello","Mumbai"),Seq("Hello","Delhi","Hello","Banglore"))
case class Tweets(filtered: Seq[String])
val df = sc.parallelize(lst).map(x=>Tweets(x)).toDF 

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count
df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value")).groupBy("value").agg(count("*").alias("cnt")).orderBy('cnt.desc).show(20,false)
```

Alternatively you can use window function.

```
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._

val lst = List(Seq("Hello","Hyd","Hello","Mumbai"),Seq("Hello","Mumbai"),Seq("Hello","Delhi","Hello","Banglore"))
case class Tweets(filtered: Seq[String])
val df = sc.parallelize(lst).map(x=>Tweets(x)).toDF 

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy('cnt.desc)

df.select(explode($"filtered").as("value")).groupBy("value").agg(count("*").alias("cnt")).withColumn("filteredrank", rank.over(w)).filter(col("filteredrank") <= 20).show()
```

Comment: Thansk Arvind. Took mtoto's advice to upgrade and I manage to break half my cluster. Will try your solution if I ever fix it.

Comment: No issues. Both solutions works on Spark 2.1 version also.

Comment: @schoon I updated the solution that works in 1.6 as well. However it is still a good idea to update.

Comment: @mtoto yes I had planned to so this for a while but now I have destroyed my cluster!!